# Table row and table data Loop on same time

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I've got a question about loop in table data and  table row. Just like a spreadsheet of  it has a 100 row then from A-Z on data, does it possible to loop table row 100 times then inside, table data is from A-Z?

Thanks for any Information.

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question? Are you asking how to write a loop?

Comment: can you be more specific about your question and so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old but for future reference I am going to answer it. When you are referring to "data" it seems to me that you are speaking of column contents aka columns.

The way you are conceptualizing accessing the data is the problem. You need to loop over the rows:

```
$query = "select * from some_table";
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::ASSOC))
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($row) - 1; $i++) {
        // Here you index the column data contents, similar to excel A-Z
        echo $row[$i];
    }    
}
```